# Disable Table pagination in material-ui Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to hide table pagination in material-UI if the data is empty array ?I couldn't find props that will hide it from documentation of table pagination in reactjs?

[pagiantion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZOhz.png)

Comment: add your sample code or add a working code  in codeSandbox or similar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below solution**

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}>
  <Table className={classes.table} aria-label="custom pagination table">
    <TableBody>
      {rows.map((row) => (
        <TableRow key={row.name}>
          <TableCell component="th" scope="row"></TableCell>
          <TableCell></TableCell>
          <TableCell></TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      ))}

    </TableBody>

    // Add below condition to hide pagination when no rows are there
    {
     rows.length > 0 && (
       <TableFooter>
         <TableRow>
           <TablePagination
             .....
             .....
             .....
             .....
             .....
           />
         </TableRow>
       </TableFooter>
     )
   }
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```